# select from string from outcome of json file in postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql, select, contains

In postgre sql my table has attributes column with json format below

```
{"color": true,"view": [184],"school": 
[805,812,855,856,857]}
```

I would like write a column that if the school contains 805,812,855 then 1 else 0. Below I tried but it is not working.

```
 case when  json_extract_path_text(attributes, 'school') in 
 [805,812,855] then 1 else 0 end as school
```

How can I fix this? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a lateral cross join to create an array for each row and see if it contains the values in [805,812,855].  Here, I'm assuming you want to make sure it contains ALL the values, not ANY of the values.

```
with data as (select * from (values
  ('{"color": true,"view": [184],"school":[805,812,855,856,857]}'::jsonb),
  ('{"color": true,"view": [184],"school":[805,812]}'::jsonb)
) as v(data))
SELECT school_arr @> '{805,812,855}'
FROM data
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT ARRAY(SELECT jsonb_array_elements_text(data -> 'school'))) d(school_arr)
;
 ?column?
----------
 t
 f
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually I got the answer

```
case when json_extract_path_text(attributes, 'school')::jsonb@>'805' then 1 
     when json_extract_path_text(attributes, 'school')::jsonb@>'812' then 1
     when json_extract_path_text(attributes, 'school')::jsonb@>'855' then 1
else 
0 end as school
```